# Adding a model to a parent view from a child view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm trying to add a new model to my parent view from a child view.

In my parent view, I render the child view like this:

```
    renderEngineOptions: function () {
        var view = new EngineOptionsView({ model: this.model });
        this.$('.engineOptions').append(view.render().el);
    },
```

In my child view(engineOptionsView), I define the parent as 'this.engine' in the initialize method:

```
    initialize: function (args) {
        this.engine = args.model;
    }
```

Then I have an html button, that when clicked, fires this event:

```
    addTurbo: function() {
        this.$('.turboOption').show();
        this.engine.turbo = new Turbo();
    }
```

Turbo is a new model that I'm trying to add to the engine.  But nothing happens.  I get no error in the console, but when I write out the engine model in the console, no turbo was ever added.

How can I add the turbo model to the parent, from the child?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a model with the `model` option, the view automatically apply it to itself, so it's available through `this.model` directly.

```
var view = new EngineOptionsView({ model: this.model });
```

in the child:

```
initialize: function (args) {
    this.engine = args.model; // not necessary
    console.log(this.model === this.engine); // same thing
}
```

You are adding the `turbo` as a property of the model

```
this.engine.turbo = new Turbo();
```

So if you want to get the `turbo` from the parent:

```
this.model.turbo;
```

If you want to add the `turbo` as an attribute of the model from the child view:

```
this.model.set('turbo', new Turbo());
```

And to get it from the parent:

```
this.model.get('turbo);
```

*Without more details, it's hard to guess where the problem is coming from.*

Comment: why backbone tag has few questions than angular js . it means backbone is not good framework ?

Comment: @Mahi Backbone is not a framework, and it was popular when there wasn't anything better at the time (~2011-2012). AngularJS is a newer *framework*, which is still highly maintained.

Comment: if you are using collection to render parent view then you can simply push a new model to the collection as this.model.collection.add({})

Comment: @nikhilmehta this is not a good idea because there's no guaranty the collection is the one you think it is. The model could be shared within multiple collections, whereas in the model, only one collection reference is kept.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks I was not aware of this fact. But I follow practice not to share model in multiple collections.